# In ST2 snippets, can $TM_CURRENT_WORD be overwritten?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

For context:
I'm writing up a snippet for Python to quickly cast a variable, like so: `variable_foo` to `str(variable_foo)`.

If I use **$SELECTION**, it works fine. But if I use **$TM_CURRENT_WORD**, it inserts the replacement value into the middle of the variable text, like this: `variastr(variable_foo)ble_foo`.

I could just keep using **$SELECTION**, but I'd prefer the added ease of not having to select the variable first with *Ctrl+D* that **$TM_CURRENT_WORD** would provide. Is there something I'm overlooking which makes this possible, or is **$SELECTION** the only way to go?

For reference, the currently functional version of the snippet: `${1:type}($SELECTION)${0}`

And an alternate version: `${1:type}${SELECTION/^.*/\($0\)/g}${0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is the intended behavior. You can use a plugin to get the behavior you want though.

```
import sublime_plugin

class ExpandInsertSnippetCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, contents=None, name=None):
        cursors = self.view.sel()
        new_cursors = []
        for cursor in cursors:
            new_cursors.append(self.view.word(cursor))
        cursors.clear()
        for cursor in new_cursors:
            cursors.add(cursor)

        self.view.run_command("insert_snippet", {"contents": contents, "name": name})
```

Rather than using the command "insert_snippet" for whatever binding you have, use "expand_insert_snippet".